# Hide particular menu item

Tags: html, css

I have following code for the Menu in wordpress:

```
<div class="menu-about-container">
   <ul id="menu-about-1" class="nav-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-574"><a href="http://10.0.3.12/aromaexpresso/?page_id=301">Our History</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to give `display:none` to **Our History**.But want something like if it is child of `menu-about-1` and `menu-about-container` then and then give `display:none`.

How can I do it?I know its very silly but I don't have any designing experience.So can any one guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you css rules:

```
.menu-about-container > #menu-about-1 > li {
display:none;
}
```

The `>` targets the immediate child of the previous selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard CSS selectors to hide any menu item that is a child:

```
.menu-about-container #menu-about-1 li.menu-item { display: none; }
```

If that particular item is always `menu-item-574` and you want to hide that one, only, use:

```
.menu-about-container #menu-about-1 li.menu-item-574 { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to hide Our history you can use

```
#menu-about-1 li{display: none}
```

But that will hide al the list items so if you want to add others in the future, and you only want to hide the fist one you should use

```
#menu-about-1 li:first{display: none}
```